# EditText in ListView gets initial value on scroll

Tags: android, listview, cursor, adapter, simplecursoradapter

I have made a custom layout for the list which contains TV, ET, Buttons.
I used SimpleCursorAdapter to bind the value of TV and ET from the DB.

The button is used to change the ET value. Suppose I have changed the value from 4 to 10.(4 was loaded from DB), and I want 4 to be updated with 10.
But as I scroll and come back again to that item the ET gets loaded with the DB value again.

Code to load data into the listView.

```
    final Cursor allDataCursor=adapterClass.getAllSubHeadsInfo(getSqlDate(incomingDate),BasicActivity.selectedHeadNumber);
    String[] from=new String[]{helper.COL_ID, helper.COL_JOIN_ENTRY_ID, helper.COL_SUB_HEAD, helper.COL_PRICE, helper.COL_QUANTITY};
    int[] to=new int[]        {R.id.tvItemNo, R.id.tvEntryNo,           R.id.tvItemName,     R.id.tvRate,      R.id.etQuantity};

    SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter= null;
    try {
        simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(AddLessActivity.this, R.layout.list_add_less, allDataCursor, from, to, 0)
        {
            @Override
            public void bindView(final View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
                super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

                //  final int row_id=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(helper.COL_ID));
                Button btnPlus= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnPlus);
                Button btnMinus= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnMinus);

                btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        EditText etQuantity= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etQuantity);
                        int qty= Integer.parseInt( etQuantity.getText().toString());
                        etQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(++qty));
                    }
                });

                btnMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        EditText etQuantity= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etQuantity);
                        int qty= Integer.parseInt( etQuantity.getText().toString());
                        if(qty>0) {
                            etQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(--qty));
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Quantity cannot be less than 0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        simpleCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    listView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);}
```

Now this loads data correctly, but as I have used SimpleCursorAdapter binding is done to DbValues. I want that the initial values are loaded by the DbValues but then changes are saved during scrolling also.

Comment: please add your code

Comment: @opoo Check it. I have added the code

Comment: Are you updating the DbValues when you are changing the value from 4 to 10?@Rishi

Comment: No I am not. I have a save button in the AppBar which will save all the ET values to db. @crazyAndroid

Comment: You need to create ViewHolder class to hold your list items of list in adapter.

Comment: @Drv That is ok but then how would I update it. Do you have some sample code with the issue covered?